# assigning values in an if statement?

Tags: php, codeigniter, coding-style, if-statement

When using code igniter I create a lot of functions that look something like this;

```
function info($id){
  $r = $this->db->select('id', 'name', 'age')->from('users')->where('id', $id)->get();
  return ($r->num_rows() == 0 ? false : $r->result());
}
```

now when I use this function I also use this function to check if a user exists and assign it to a variable.

So it will be used something like

```
if( ($user = $this->user->info($_GET['id'])) === false )
  die('User not found');

//now we can continue and $user contains the user info
```

My question is, is there any reason this is a bad idea?

as far as I am aware this is the same as

```
$user = $this->user->info($_GET['id']);
if( $user === false )
  die('User not found');
```

but in my opinion actually easier to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, the two methods are identical.  The only difference is clarity.  I believe that the second method is much clearer than the first.  You should discuss your conventions with other developers working on your projects and set the standards to code by.  Consistency is the most important thing.

The disadvantage of the first method is it's difficult to tell if you meant to use `==` instead of just `=`.  In the second method, there is no such ambiguity.